# How do I change the browser accept-language

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

If the user has their browser set to fr-CA, for instance but my site has the option to view the page in another available language (like English). How can I override the accept-language header so that I can reload using the specified language?

I was attempting to simply change the Accept-Language header and then reload the page, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
Ok, so I'm getting people explaining to me what localization is so I must not have asked this properly.

My site currently has globalization set to auto in the web.config so it will automatically set the thread culture to whichever language was negotiated at app start. By default, the user's browser will send the accept-language header based on the language settings for the browser which, like someone pointed out below, average users have no clue what those are, where those are, or how to change them. In any case, let's call this default behavior that the browser will handle the language headers first. However, as a FEATURE, I want to allow the user to change this accept-language header from the page. For instance, in the application, the language settings will normally be determined by cookie or by user preference (via profile settings), but on the landing/login page (particularly if this your first time logging in on a certain computer), I have no idea who you are so I only have your browser settings to go off of. But let's say that you're traveling on business and accessing this site from an american computer, the page loads in English and you can't read it and you have no idea how to change the browser language. Would it not be nice to have the option to choose your language from a drop down menu or icon or something? I think it would be.

So in order to do that, I need to be able to change that accept-language header and reload the page. This is where I'm not sure how to proceed.

I've tried `navigator.language = <selected language>` and `xhr.setRequestHeader` but these don't seem to work.

Comment: Dont know if I it helps but I use the Accept-Language to deliver the related content and deliver a fallback if there's no locale for the Accepted-Language available on the server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might be wrong but the locale settings is not something you change in your code.
This is determined by the browser's user configuration.
If you are using an HttpClient you definitely send the value you want for Accept-Language header to the server, but don't expect to change this from your code and make it effective in ALL the requests originated in the browser.

Common practice is to set a custom cookie with your user's language preference. By default you should populate this cookie with the value on Accept-Language header.
In ASP.NET MVC there is a setting so both **Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture** and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture get's set according to the user's browser configuration:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
</system.web>
```

You can then create an ActionFilter that would check the custom language cookie and will set the **Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture** accordingly.

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is used to determine which resources the code should use. While Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is used for all the numeric and dates handling.

This is how that action filter might look like:

```
public class LanguageActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var langCookie = GetOrSetLanguageCookie(filterContext.HttpContext);
        var culture = new CultureInfo(langCookie.Value);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }

    private HttpCookie GetOrSetLanguageCookie(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[Constants.LanguageCookieName];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            //set the cookie for first time
            cookie = new HttpCookie(Constants.LanguageCookieName, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name)
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                Path = "/"
            };
            context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        return cookie;
    }
}
```

**Pleae Note:**

- Even when your user selects, let's say "es-Ar" in your interface, and you set your UICulture accordingly for that user, IF the user's browser is configured with en-US dates posted for that user will be parse using the English convention, so float number will.

IE: If the user in USA with a browser set to en_US chooses to use the Spanish interface of your app, when this user post information to the server dates like:

1/5/2015 will be parse as January 5th in the server, rather than May 1st.

Numbers like 1,900 will be parsed as 1900 in the server rather than 1.900.

I learned this the hard way. 
I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749663/asp-net-mvc4-jquery-globalize-and-proper-globalization) that was never answered.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Ok, so this is actually how my site is set up, with auto locale in the web.config. I use this because it'll take care of the language prority list. But my question was how to override it. By default, the browser sends those language headers and my site will honor them the best it can. I want to override what the browser is sending so that I can allow the user to choose by hand should they so please as a feature.

Comment: On a side note, I know how to change this in jquery for ajax calls, but I really need a way to do it via post back. i.e. "Change the header and reload this page."

Comment: I answered your question in the first lines; sorry if I went too far into details, I thought it would be helpful in the case you didn't have the full picture.

You can't change this in your code. You can definitely can change this header for a request your code initiates, but you can't do it globally so every subsequent request initiated in the browser now have the appropriated header given the user language selection.

Comment: The contradiction here is that even when you are surfacing a culture, if the browser is configured with another culture the later is the one that prevails and the one your server would use for date & number parsing in the model binding.

In my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749663/asp-net-mvc4-jquery-globalize-and-proper-globalization I was asking if this is actually correct or if there was any other solution available.

What I ended up doing, was presenting calendars and formatting numbers in the client based on the Accept-Language header which corresponds to the CurrentCulture

Comment: Ok, so I'm trotting down this path. What I did is set a cookie with the selected language and then I attempt to read that out in an action filter. Here's what's happening. I have my web.config set up as you suggested, my browser is set to fr-CA, my test is setting the cookie to es-MX. The action filter is succesfully reading that and setting Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and UI culture to the value in the cookie. By the time it gets the controller, the culture is back to fr-CA. I feel like the auto culture from web.config is being executed somewhere in between

Comment: Try removing the setting from the web.config, use the Accept-Language for the default when no selection has been made by the user yet.
I'm kind of confused now. It seems that due to the web.config setting, your culture is set based on the Accept-Language, regardless what you are doing on the filter. 
However this seems to happen to CurrentCulture only, otherwise you would be seeing the wrong language on the screen, which is not the case (at least not in my case).

Comment: If after removing the web.confg setting you still see the CurrentCulture being stepped on by Accept-Language, then this is default behavior (which is what I assumed back in the day).
If not, then you helped me solving a problem I gave a not so good solution in the past :)

Comment: I removed the setting but it is still honoring the browser setting even if i set enableClientBasedCulture to false. Interesting. Another thought I had was perhaps it isn't allowing you to change the culture once the thread has started? I tried changing the culture to es-MX right in the controller action just to see if it would take and it does not!

Comment: Ok, it seems that my assumption back then was accurate :)
Remember there is a difference between CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture and everywhere I read they only recommend changing the latter.

Comment: So what are the implications? Are you saying that I can switch the ui culture which will switch the resource files, however numerics will continue to honor the browser's accepted language?

Comment: Yes, that was my conclusion. So I had to handle datetime and numeric operations in the client as per the Accept-Language culture; regardless what the user choose on the interface.

Answer (score 6):

The [`Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header is a request header, so it is sent by the browser (or other client software). On your server, you can ignore it by doing nothing. That is, it has no effect as such; all depends on whether your server-side code recognizes it and takes some action. So you cannot and need not change the header sent by the browser.

The user can change the `Accept-Language` header sent by the browser using the browser’s preference settings. E.g., in Chrome, go to “Settings”,  click on “Show advanced settings...”, scroll down to “Languages”, click on “Language and input settings...”, and then add languages and drag to order them.

This is not something people do often, and most people have no idea of the existence of such settings. So what the browser sends is usually some factory defaults. They can be rather strange, e.g. `Accept-Language: fr-CA` would mean, by the protocol, “if you, dear server, have different language versions of the resource I’m requesting for, please give me Canadian French; if you don’t have it, I don’t care which version you give”. This means that if the resource exists in generic French (of French French), or in English, these would have no preference over, say, Swahili or Volapük version. So a more sensible header would normally be `Accept-Language: fr-CA, fr, en`, and this is in practice how you should deal with `Accept-Language: fr-CA`.

Comment: "So you cannot and need not change the header sent by the browser" - yes, you can.